# Oracle Script File Execution in *.bat file not completing

Tags: oracle, batch-file, windows-xp, oracle9i

I have the following *.bat file executing itself on a schedule. This file consists of different tasks, primarily involves in having a the backup dump file exported to the Test DB Machine every day.

```
@echo off
@echo %time%
del C:\Factory\index.sql
echo exporting indexes...
Imp jksbschema/password file=C:\DBDUMP\jksb.dmp full=yes log=C:\Factory\log\dump_index.log indexfile=index.sql
@echo %time%
echo connecting to Oracle...
echo Delete and Re-Creation of User
sqlplus "sys/password as sysdba" @C:\Factory\script\step_1.sql
echo importing dump file begins...
@echo %time%
Imp jksbschema/password file=C:\DBDUMP\jksb.dmp full=yes log=C:\Factory\log\dump.log Compile=n INDEXES=n
echo Applying security priviledges
@echo %time%
sqlplus "sys/password as sysdba" @C:\Factory\script\step_2.sql
@echo %time%
ssr 0 "CONNECT" "REM CONNECT" C:\Factory\index.sql
echo Loading Indexes....`enter code here`
sqlplus "jksbschema/password as sysdba" @C:\Factory\index.sql
@echo %time%
exit
shutdown.exe -r -t 00
```

Since its a long operation, I execute itself on every night, expecting it to be ready next morning. I also include a command restart the machine once the entire process is over. All the command finishes without asking an input expect the following command:

```
sqlplus "jksbschema/password as sysdba" @C:\Factory\index.sql
```

after the above command executes, the batch file asks for an input to exit the process as the snapshot below says

[image]

Can anybody help in automatically finish the job and restart itself, rather than ask for an input after the index.sql file is loaded?

Comment: When you execute sqlplus can you finish the line with <quit.txt, and create a file name "quit.txt" with "quit" in it?

Comment: Do you mean to say to have the command "<quit.txt" at the end of the index.sql file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file named **quit.txt**, inside it put the text "quit".

Where you see the lines that execute sqlplus, like this one:

```
sqlplus "jksbschema/password as sysdba" @C:\Factory\index.sql
```

change them to this:

```
sqlplus "jksbschema/password as sysdba" @C:\Factory\index.sql < quit.txt
```

Comment: Or just redirect the input from `index.sql`, replacing `@` with `<`; SQL*Plus will exit when it runs out of input, even without an explicit `exit` in the script. (I'm assuming redirection works in Windows...)

Comment: @LachlanB, Thanks a lot! it worked well. Thanks Again! (y) Alex Poole, not forgetting you as well! (y)

Answer (score 0):

Old stuff, but however: Let "exit;" be the last command of your SQL script. This tells sqlplus to quit and finish execution.